# Javascript How do I split a JSON array, find the max value out of the numbers, then grab the name to go with it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an external JSON file with an array that contains some information I need, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to split it.

```
  {
    "video": "incoming2.mp4",
    "description": "Updated every 30 minutes: - Created 2015-07-07 14:45:29 EST",
    "title": "304 Angstrom Last 3 days",
    "timestamp": "2015-07-07 14:45:29 EST",
    "sort": ["20150707144529", "incoming2.mp4"],
    "thumb": "thumb/incoming2.png"
  },
```

Here is a small part of the JSON file, the place you should direct your attention to is `"sort": ["20150707144529", "incoming2.mp4"],`, I want to create an array in my javascript using all of these within the file, and splitting them into their own data within the array like this: `arrayName[0]` would be `"20150707144529"` while `arrayName[1]` would be `"incoming2.mp4"`. Then, after it is split, I want to find the highest value based on the first number within sort, and grab the file name directly after it and store it in a variable.

(ps: I know I'm kinda bad at wording things, so if you need me to clarify what I'm asking, just ask me to do so)

**EDIT:**

How I'm calling the json file:

```
$(document).ready(function vidTitle() {
    $.getJSON("sun.json", function(json1) {
        //json stuff here
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is (kinda sort of but not really) my full(-ish) json file

```
[
  {
    "video": "incoming.mp4",
    "description": "Updated every 30 minutes: - Created 2015-07-07 14:45:24 EST",
    "title": "193 Angstrom Last 3 days",
    "timestamp": "2015-07-07 14:45:24 EST",
    "sort": ["20150707144524", "incoming.mp4"],
    "thumb": "thumb/incoming.png"
  },
  {
    "video": "incoming2.mp4",
    "description": "Updated every 30 minutes: - Created 2015-07-07 14:45:29 EST",
    "title": "304 Angstrom Last 3 days",
    "timestamp": "2015-07-07 14:45:29 EST",
    "sort": ["20150707144529", "incoming2.mp4"],
    "thumb": "thumb/incoming2.png"
  },
  {
    "video": "incoming3.mp4",
    "description": "Updated every 30 minutes: - Created 2015-07-07 14:47:35 EST",
    "title": "171 Angstrom Last 3 days",
    "timestamp": "2015-07-07 14:47:35 EST",
    "sort": ["20150707144735", "incoming3.mp4"],
    "thumb": "thumb/incoming3.png"
  }
  //Basically, a bunch more of what is above with different data
]
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far. Without code its hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/qaf1q2ao/

I removed all of the properties in the JSON that we don't care about.  I threw some more sample data in an array keyed by `data`.  This just searches for the highest `sort` value for each object in the `data` array, keeping track of the index of the current maximum.  Once we are finished with the loop, `maxIndex` contains the index into the array that contains the highest `sort` value.

```
$.getJSON('sun.json', function(json) {
    var max = 0;
    var maxIndex = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
        var val = parseInt(json[index].sort[0]);
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
            maxIndex = index;
        }
    }

    alert('highest is ' + json[maxIndex].sort[1]);
});
```

Output

> highest is incoming2.mp4

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how would I modify this to work with an external file called with jQuery: `$.getJSON("sun.json", function(json1)`?

Comment: @Calebbait see my updated code in my answer.  You can just put this code in your success function.  Also, I wasn't sure of the structure of your JSON data, so you may need to modify the logic that uses the data to use the correct property names and indexes.  I would need to see more of your JSON data to help you with this.

Comment: I edited my post to show more of the structure of the json file.

Comment: Ok so you can just treat the `json` (or in your case, you called it `json1`) parameter to the success function as an array.  Take a look at my updated answer, I removed all references to `data`, which is a key that I introduced when  adding sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm could be something like this:

1. Read the JSON from file
2. Parse the JSON into a JavaScript object variable (say `videos`)
3. Set a `max_object` variable to `null`
4. For each `video` in `videos`, look at the value of `video.sort[0]`
5. If the `video.sort[0]` value is greater than `max_object.sort[0]` (or if `max_object` is null), overwrite `max_object` with the `video`
6. Move to the next `video` in step 4

At the end of this process, your `max_object` variable will hold the video data of the video with the largest `sort` value.